# Error in Selenium : ERROR: Couldn't read tbsCertificate as SEQUENCE, ERROR: Failed parsing Certificate

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, error-handling

I'm trying to execute a selenium program in Python to go to a URL and input some information. I'm new to selenium and any help regarding this would be appreciated. Here's my code (i have two different files):

first file:

```
import types
import typing
import os
import datetime
import zbiranje_podatkov.konstante as konst
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options


class Letalske(webdriver.Chrome):
    def __init__(self, driver_path=r"C:/SeleniumDrivers"):
        self.driver_path = driver_path
        os.environ['PATH'] += r"C:/SeleniumDrivers"
        super(Letalske, self).__init__()
        self.implicitly_wait(30)
        self.maximize_window()

    def prva_stran(self):
        self.get(konst.BASE_URL)

    def izberi_kraj_odhoda(self, kraj_odhoda):
        odhod = self.find_element(By.ID, "pol")
        odhod.clear()
        odhod.send_keys(kraj_odhoda)
        letalisce_odhod = self.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "sugg")
        letalisce_odhod.click()

    def izberi_kraj_prihoda(self, kraj_prihoda):
        prihod = self.find_element(By.ID, "odr")
        prihod.clear()
        prihod.send_keys(kraj_prihoda)
        letalisce_prihod = self.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "sugg")
        letalisce_prihod.click()
```

second file:

```
from zbiranje_podatkov.skyscanner import Letalske

with Letalske() as bot:
    bot.prva_stran()
    bot.izberi_kraj_odhoda("Zagreb")
    bot.izberi_kraj_prihoda("Tokyo")
```

I saw this solution but I just don't know where to use it

```
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()

options.add_experimental_option('excludeSwitches', ['enable-logging'])

driver = webdriver.Chrome(
    service= Service(chromedriver_path), 
    options=options,
)
```